# How to describe Array with hole in JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsdoc

I want use JsDoc to describe an Array of number, while the array may contain holes. What is the best way to describe the holes?

What I'm trying: (but holes should not be as same as undefined, IMO)

```
/** @type {Array.<(number|undefined)>} */
let myArray = [0, 1, , 3];
```

Comment: I think that's how you do it. Holes technically are undefined... they have an undefined value

Comment: In my opinion it should be `@type {SparseArray.<number>}`, or just `@type {Array.<number>}` with a comment about it being sparse (and leave it to your code to manage which elements get assigned a value), but I haven't seen any JsDoc that supports the sparse concept. I agree that `number|undefined` isn't really satisfactory because presumably that would allow you to push/assign the value `undefined` and you don't want that.